# How to balance a database transaction workflow with a pending transaction type?

Tags: database, t-sql, relational-database, transactional

I have a products table and a table to describe transactions against the product table as defined a stack exchange answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150339/building-an-inventory-database.

There are 4 transaction types:

1. purchase - removes quantity from product
2. received -add additional quantity to product
3. chargeback - balances ledger for discounts or
   products with sales prices
4. rollback - adds quantity removed from
   purchase transaction e.g. it balances the inventory
5. pending*** -
   represents quantity on hold in user shopping cart

How would the inventory balance if the transaction workflow for a purchase is:

1. create a received transaction for 1 product (inventory increments by 1)
2. create a pending transaction for 1 product (user select checkout option in interface, inventory decrements by 1)
3. create a purchase transaction for 1 product (user pays for product in interface, inventory decrements by 1)

The math for this workflow does not add up as the final on hand quantity for the sum of the above scenario is -1. How would you go about this using the pending transactions? I'm open to ideas.

Thanks for your help in advance!

** UPDATE **

I decided to go with:

1. removing the chargeback transaction because pricing id will be on
   the transaction and will be calculated in a different business
   process
2. using a rollback transaction for the pending transaction when
   pending transaction hours > 24 or if a subsequent purchase
   transaction is made referencing the pending transaction in question

This way, the transaction table can essentially be a read only table that only allows inserts (e.g. transactions of the above types).

Going this route should alleviate the need for a shopping cart related tables that represent transient data as an Orders table will contain necessary references to relevant transaction lines. Plus when I need to find out how if a user has "shopping cart" items, the query would be a select (with no locks) on the transaction table by user.

Is there anything standing out to you that I should be aware of with this method?

Comment: I think you need to decide what *pending* means to your business. When you're talking about transaction types, you say that *pending* represents what's in the cart. (Nothing about *pending* having some effect on inventory.) But when you're talking about inventory balance, you say that a pending transaction decrements inventory. Which is it?

Comment: I think that is essentially the problem I'm trying to solve. A table solution could be to create a "cart" table and store items currently in the cart there since the inventory wouldn't decrement until a purchase transaction is made. But, I think creating an additional table (entity) to store cart products would add an additional level of complexity in keeping up with inventory on hand since the business rule is: if a product is in the cart, it is not available for others to put in their cart. So, in other words, I'd like to see if using a pending transaction (decrements inventory) would work?

Comment: If the rule is really *"if a product is in the cart, it is not available for others"*, then you should check and decrement inventory (or decrement shadow inventory) when you add to a cart, and *purchase* should check inventory before doing anything. Think about what to do with long-term carts and abandoned carts (including how you know it's abandoned). All these answers are application-specific; you're the only one of us that can answer them. (Consider that *you* probably shouldn't try answering these questions; the business owners should.)

Comment: This is for one of my apps, so I can make the design decision. I'm an engineer too, so I am interested in what you and others have done in similar instances. Whether I create a cart table or pending transaction, you are correct that I still have to deal with abandoned carts. There will be a process that monitors the transaction ledger for pending transactions and insert rollback transactions after 24 hours. My thoughts have cleared up quite a bit with your help. I think what I will do is insert a rollback transaction which will perform the adjustment that will balance the inventory on purchase